# Как прописать пагинацию на основной странице блога wp

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста вот что - необходимо на основной странице блога где выводятся все посты со всех категорий вывести по 5 постов на страницу и чтобы была пагинация. На странице с категориями я ее вывел стандартным способом `the_post_pagination`, а вот на основной странице где все категории он почему-то не выдает навигацию.. Вот небольшой участок кода с тем, как пробовал вывести посты и обработать пагинацию.

```
<div class="blog__inner">

              <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
              <div class="blog__content">

                <?php

                  $posts = get_posts( array(
                    'numberposts' => 5,
                    'category'    => 0,
                    'orderby'     => 'date',
                    'order'       => 'DESC',
                    'include'     => array(),
                    'exclude'     => array(),
                    'meta_key'    => '',
                    'meta_value'  =>'',
                    'post_type'   => 'post',
                    'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
                  ) );

                  foreach( $posts as $post ){
                    setup_postdata($post);
                      ?>
                <article class="blog__post">
                  <div class="blog__minicard">
                    <h2 class="blog__minicard_title">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                      <time class="post__date" datetime="<?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?>">
                        <?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?></time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog__minicard_content">
                      <div class="blog__minicard_images">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                          <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
                      </div>
                      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog__tab_line"></div>
                </article>
                <?php
                  }?>
                <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
                <?php

                  wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс

               ?>


              </div>
```

Только бы мне это сделать без подключения плагинов. (я пробовал, но тогда начинается проблема на странице с категориями). Если кто знает как, подскажите. Заранее благодарен.

Вот таким образом получилось вывести пагинацию, но при выборе страницы переход осуществляется(в адресной строке по крайней мере), а вот посты остаются те же, то есть страница не меняется и в пагинации отображается так же страница активной. В чем проблема?

```
<?php 
              query_posts( $args );
              while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                ?>
                <article class="blog__post">
                  <div class="blog__minicard">
                  <h2 class="blog__minicard_title">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                      <time class="post__date" datetime="<?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?>"><?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?></time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog__minicard_content">
                      <div class="blog__minicard_images">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
                      </div>
                      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog__tab_line"></div>
                </article>
                <?php
              } ?>
              <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
              <?php

              // пагинация

              // вернем global $wp_query
              wp_reset_query();
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

После раздумий и перебора различных вариантов нашлось решение. Проблема с пагинацией во втором примере кода вопроса была в том, что пагинации не передавалось на какой странице мы находимся. Может кому пригодится. Вот итоговый пример кода

```
<?php 
              $args = array(
                  'paged'         => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
                'post_type'   => 'post',
                'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
              );
              query_posts( $args );
              while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                ?>
                <article class="blog__post">
                  <div class="blog__minicard">
                  <h2 class="blog__minicard_title">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                      <time class="post__date" datetime="<?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?>"><?php the_time('F j,  Y'); ?></time>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog__minicard_content">
                      <div class="blog__minicard_images">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
                      </div>
                      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="blog__tab_line"></div>
                </article>
                <?php
              } ?>
              <?php 
              the_posts_pagination(); ?>
              <?php
              wp_reset_query();
              ?>
```